# How is it possible an endpoint method returns null when null is never returned?

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine, endpoint

This method belongs to my endpoint in an Android project with Google App Engine backend in Android Studio:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getAllUnclaimedLeftovers")
public Collection<Leftover> getAllUnclaimedLeftovers() {
    Collection<Leftover> unclaimedLeftoverOffers = new ArrayList<Leftover>();

    for(Leftover leftover : ofy().load().type(Leftover.class)) {
        if (!leftover.isClaimed() && leftover.isValid()) {
            unclaimedLeftoverOffers.add(leftover);
        }
    }

    return unclaimedLeftoverOffers;
}
```

As you can see, `null` will never be returned.
Here you can see a method on the app side of the project using the previous backend method via a client library generated by the corresponding gradle commands.

```
public static Collection<Leftover> getAllUnclaimedLeftovers() throws IOException {
    try {
        return Proxy.getEndpoint().getAllUnclaimedLeftovers().execute().getItems();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("DataStore_UnclaimedLeftovers_Error", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

My question is: how is it possible that the last method returns a `null` object?

Now I'm checking for `null` objects and everything works and the app and backend are deployed and work correctly.

The method `getAllUnclaimedLeftovers()` is used in:

```
private class UnclaimedLeftoversTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            setUnclaimedLeftovers(LeftoverProxy.getAllUnclaimedLeftovers());
            setIsUnclaimedLeftoversSucceeded(true);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            setIsUnclaimedLeftoversSucceeded(false);
            return null;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            setIsUnclaimedLeftoversSucceeded(false);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

LeftoverProxy.getAllUnclaimedLeftovers() refers to `null` object.

When taking a look in the automatically generated endpoint lib:

```
public GetAllUnclaimedLeftovers getAllUnclaimedLeftovers() throws java.io.IOException {    
    GetAllUnclaimedLeftovers result = new GetAllUnclaimedLeftovers();
    initialize(result);
    return result;
}

public class GetAllUnclaimedLeftovers extends EndpointRequest<com.frigoshare.endpoint.model.LeftoverCollection> {

    private static final String REST_PATH = "leftovercollection";


    protected GetAllUnclaimedLeftovers() {
      super(Endpoint.this, "GET", REST_PATH, null,   com.frigoshare.endpoint.model.LeftoverCollection.class);
    }

...
}
```

Constructor of the super class:

```
public EndpointRequest(
  Endpoint client, String method, String uriTemplate, Object content, Class<T> responseClass) {
    super(
        client,
        method,
        uriTemplate,
        content,
        responseClass);
    }
```

When searching in AbstractGoogleClientRequest I found the `execute()`:

```
 /**
   * Sends the metadata request to the server and returns the parsed metadata response.
   *
   * <p>
   * Subclasses may override by calling the super implementation.
   * </p>
   *
   * @return parsed HTTP response
   */
  public T execute() throws IOException {
    HttpResponse response = executeUnparsed();
    if (Void.class.equals(responseClass)) {
      response.ignore();
      return null;
    }
    return response.parseAs(responseClass);
  }
```

But this digging in Google's code makes no sense, the libs must implement the correct behaviour. I mean or you get a respone or you get a failure and throw an IOException, but not something in between?

Comment: I assume you get a NullPointerExecption somewhere? Are you sure, that the null pointer is not for some other object (e.g. the endpoint itself), than the unclaimed leftovers?

Comment: @peshkira: I added an other method in the chain which receives a null object. I know this is null because I cannot invoke a method on the Collection (e.g.: size())

Comment: Maybe the object receiving the call to the method `getAllUnclaimedLeftovers` is an instance of a sub class that has overridden this method (and maybe returns `null`).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I guess a null is returned by the wrapper classes in the client libs, but it makes no sense why the automatically generated code decides itself to return null in my opinion so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I receive `Null` when fetching empty collections from my `GAE` backend.
I receive `jsonMappingException` when trying to push empty collections to my `GAE` backend.
So I guess that `JSON` (or the `Gradle` plugin for `Android Studio`) is not able to handle empty collections in both directions.

As this project is for a course of mine, I've also seen other student's projects with this weird behaviour.